# Unit testing a Restlet extractor

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, restlet

I'm looking for some guidance on real unit testing for Restlet components, and specifically extractors. There is plenty of advice on running JUnit to rest entire endpoints, but being picky this is not unit testing, but integration testing. I really don't want to have set up an entire routing system and Spring just to check an extractor against a mock data repository.

The extractor looks like this:

```
public class CaseQueryExtractor extends Extractor {

    protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
        extractFromQuery("offset", "offset", true);
        extractFromQuery("limit", "limit", true);

        // Stuff happens...

        attributes.put("query", query);
        return CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking part of the virtue of Restlets is that its nice routing model ought to make unit testing easy, but I can't figure out what I need to do to actually exercise `extractFromQuery` and its friends, and all my logic that builds a query object, without mocking so much that I'm losing testing against a realistic web request.

And yes, I am using Spring, but I don't want to have to set the whole context for this -- I'm not integration testing as I haven't actually finished the app yet. I'm happy to inject manually, once I know what I need to make to get this method called.

Here's where I'm at now:

```
public class CaseQueryExtractorTest {

    private class TraceRestlet extends Restlet {
        // Does snothing, but prevents warning shouts
    }

    private CaseQueryExtractor extractor;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {

        Restlet mock = new TraceRestlet();
        extractor = new CaseQueryExtractor();
        extractor.setNext(mock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasicExtraction() {

         Reference reference = new Reference();
         reference.addQueryParameter("offset", "5");
         reference.addQueryParameter("limit", "3");
         Request request = new Request(Method.GET, reference);
         Response response = extractor.handle(request);
         extractor.handle(request, response);

         CaseQuery query = (CaseQuery) request.getAttributes().get("query");
         assertNotNull(query);
     }
}
```

Which of course fails, as whatever set up I am doing isn't enough to make Restlets able to extract the query parameters.

Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: Which version of Restlet do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a test module in Restlet that can provide you some hints about unit testing. See https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/tree/master/modules/org.restlet.test/src/org/restlet/test.

You can have a look at class `HeaderTestCase` (see https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.test/src/org/restlet/test/HeaderTestCase.java).

For information, if you use attributes from request, your unit test will pass ;-) See below:

```
public class CaseQueryExtractor extends Extractor {

    protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
        extractFromQuery("offset", "offset", true);
        extractFromQuery("limit", "limit", true);

        // Stuff happens...

        CaseQuery query = new CaseQuery();

        Map<String,Object> attributes = request.getAttributes();
        attributes.put("query", query);
        return CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

I don't know if you want to go further...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Many thanks for this. I did notice request attributes just worked. Part of the issue was I'd expected  `extractFromQuery` to actually extract and it doesn't, it sets it up so that these params are only extracted when calling super(). And thanks for the pointer to the test module: I would be using the test module a whole lot more if it was split into two: a test-core and test-ext, because the slew of dependencies from Restlet's test module made the build very complicated.

Comment: In fact, it's something normal here. The extractor is a filter so the method `beforeHandle` does the stuff ;-) It's not always clear to me what you want actually to test... Can you provide to me any more hints? Thanks!

Comment: I have a CaseQuery instance which I use to filter the repository. I want to test that I can build one from about six different query string parameters. Adding a call to `super.beforeHandle(request, response);` in the ... stuff happens ... seems necessary to make the extractor make the query string values accessible (which felt odd) -- with that, the testing seems easy. I'd actually thought this was my broken testing, not the actual intended behaviour for `extractFromQuery`.